# Environments in R, mapply and get

Tags: r, get, environment, mapply

Let `x<-2` in the global env:

```
x <-2 
x
[1] 2
```

Let `a` be a function that defines another `x` locally and uses `get`:

```
a<-function(){
  x<-1
  get("x")
}
```

This function correctly gets `x` from the local enviroment:

```
a()
[1] 1
```

Now let's define a function `b` as below, that uses `mapply` with `get`:

```
b<-function(){
  x<-1
  mapply(get,"x")
}
```

If I call `b`, it seems that `mapply` makes `get` not search the function environment first. Instead, it tries to get `x` directly form the global enviroment, and if `x` is not defined in the global env, it gives an error message:

```
b()
x 
2 
rm(x)
b()
Error in (function (x, pos = -1L, envir = as.environment(pos), mode = "any",  : 
  object 'x' not found
```

The solution to this is to explicitly define `envir=environment()`.

```
c<-function(){
  x<-1
  mapply(get,"x", MoreArgs = list(envir=environment()))
}

c()
x 
1
```

But I would like to know what exactly is going on here. What is `mapply`doing? (And why? is this the expected behavior?) Is this "pitfall" common in other R functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `get` looks into the envivornment that its called from but here we are passing `get` to `mapply` and then calling `get` from the local environment within `mapply`.   If `x` is not found within the `mapply` local environment then it looks the into the parent environment of that, i.e. into `environment(mapply)` (which is the lexical environment that mapply was defined in which is the base namespace environment); if it is not there either, it looks into the parent of that, which is the global environment, i.e. your R workspace.

This is because R uses *lexical* scoping, [as opposed to dynamic scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope).

We can show this by getting a variable that exists within `mapply`.

```
 x <- 2
 b2<-function(){
   x<-1
   mapply(get, "USE.NAMES")
 }
 b2() # it finds USE.NAMES in mapply
 ## USE.NAMES 
 ##     TRUE
```

In addition to the workaround involving `MoreArgs` shown in the question this also works since it causes the search to look into the local environment within `b` after failing to find it `mapply`.   (This is just for illustrating what is going on and in actual practice we would prefer the workaround shown in the question.)

```
x <- 2
b3 <-function(){
   x<-1
   environment(mapply) <- environment()
   mapply(get, "x")
}
b3()
## 1
```

**ADDED** Expanded explanation.  Also note that we can view the chain of environments like this:

```
> debug(get)
> b()
debugging in: (function (x, pos = -1L, envir = as.environment(pos), mode = "any", 
    inherits = TRUE) 
.Internal(get(x, envir, mode, inherits)))(dots[[1L]][[1L]])
debug: .Internal(get(x, envir, mode, inherits))
Browse[2]> envir
<environment: 0x0000000021ada818>
Browse[2]> ls(envir) ### this shows that envir is the local env in mapply
[1] "dots"      "FUN"       "MoreArgs"  "SIMPLIFY"  "USE.NAMES"
Browse[2]> parent.env(envir) ### the parent of envir is the base namespace env
<environment: namespace:base>
Browse[2]> parent.env(parent.env(envir)) ### and grandparent of envir is the global env
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Thus, the ancestory of environments potentially followed is this (where arrow points to parent):

```
local environment within mapply --> environment(mapply) --> .GlobalEnv
```

where `environment(mapply)` equals `asNamespace("base")`, the base namespace environment.

Comment: In other words, it's a clash between dynamic and lexical scoping.

Comment: Actually, not quite right. `identical((function() { mapply(function(x) environment(), 1) })()[[1]], baseenv())` is `FALSE`. It is not the case that it looks in `environment(mapply)`. As you can tell from the [the source code](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/91aaa43312da6b0e6906ef221fd7756dc0459843/src/main/mapply.c#L105), the problem is an unadulterated call to the built-in C function [`eval`](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/91aaa43312da6b0e6906ef221fd7756dc0459843/src/main/eval.c#L476), which in this case creates its own temp environment branch directly off `baseenv()`

Comment: @Robert,  The relevant calculation is actually `trace(get, quote({print(identical(parent.env(envir), environment(mapply))); print(identical(environment(mapply), asNamespace("base")))}))
; b()` which yields two TRUE values - i.e. the parent of the `envir` arg of `get` is indeed `environment(mapply)` or equivalently `asNamespace("base")`.  It is true that the reference to base environment would more correctly be termed the base namespace environment (rather than just base environment) although they are often identified with each other.  I have added the word namespace to be accurate.
`

Answer (score 3):

R is lexically scoped, not dynamically scoped, meaning that when you search through parent environments to find a value, you are searching through the lexical parents (as written in the source code), not through the dynamic parents (as invoked).  Consider this example:

```
x <- "Global!"
fun1 <- function() print(x)
fun2 <- function() {
  x <- "Local!"
  fun1a <- function() print(x)
  fun1()           # fun2() is dynamic but not lexical parent of fun1()
  fun1a()          # fun2() is both dynamic and lexical parent of fun1a() 
}
fun2()
```

outputs:

```
[1] "Global!"
[1] "Local!"
```

In this case `fun2` is the lexical parent of `fun1a`, but not of `fun1`.  Since `mapply` is not defined inside your functions, your functions are not the lexical parents of `mapply` and the `x`s defined therein are not directly accessible to `mapply`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is an interplay with built-in C code. Namely, considering the following:

```
fx <- function(x) environment()
env <- NULL; fn <- function() { env <<- environment(); mapply(fx, 1)[[1]] }
```

Then

```
env2 <- fn()
identical(env2, env)
# [1] FALSE
identical(parent.env(env2), env)
# [1] FALSE
identical(parent.env(env2), globalenv())
# [1] TRUE
```

More specifically, the problem lies in the [underlying C code](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/91aaa43312da6b0e6906ef221fd7756dc0459843/src/main/mapply.c#L105), which fails to consider executing environment, and hands it off to an as-is [underlying C `eval`](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/91aaa43312da6b0e6906ef221fd7756dc0459843/src/main/eval.c#L476) call which creates a temp environment branching directly off of `R_GlobalEnv`.

Note this really is what is going on, since no level of stack nesting fixes the issue:

```
env <- NULL; fn2 <- function() { env <<- environment(); (function() { mapply(fx, 1)[[1]] })() }
identical(parent.env(fn2()), globalenv())
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Robert, I'm not familiar with the underlying C code, but doesn't the lexical argument explain the behavior you are seeing here?  Since `fx` is defined in the global env, its parent environment is always global env, no matter where you call it.

Comment: I see! I believe you are correct. I'm writing from my phone but we can confirm that hypothesis by nesting the stack from `fx` rather than `fn2`. Can you try it? There should be a chain of two environments now up to globalenv.

Comment: `fx <- function(x) (function() environment())(); parent.env(parent.env(fn()))` returns `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>`.