# Why doesn't 'with' pass variable scope through nested functions?

Tags: r, scope

In R, if I create an environment and then use `with` to evaluate a function in that enviroment, the function has normally access to the variables. However, if I nest functions, for some reason, they go out of scope. Can you explain to me why this is the case?

Example:

Create a new environment with a variable called `x`

```
E = new.env();
E$x = c(1,2,3)
```

Using `with` I can print this variable:

```
with(E, print(x));
#[1] 1 2 3
```

But now if I nest this function, it no longer works:

```
printMe = function() { print(x); }
with(E, printMe())
#Error in print(x) : object 'x' not found
```

I know I can make it work again like so:

```
printMe = function(x) { print(x); }
with(E, printMe(x))
#[1] 1 2 3
```

But I don't understand -- if `with` creates an environment, why can't the nested function see the `x`?  It works if you attach it:

```
attach(E)
printMe()
#[1] 1 2 3
```

I think I'm just missing something about scoping, but what's the recommended way of doing this? Or, to put my question another way: why can't nested functions in `with` access free variables?

Comment: You can also use an `envir` argument and use `get` instead of `print`, for example `printMe <- function(envir = parent.frame()) { get("x", envir = envir) }; with(E, printMe)` This evaluates `x` in the environment one step up in the chain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[R is lexically scoped not dynamically scoped.](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scope) The environment of `printMe` is the *Global Environment*, because it was defined in the *Global Environment*:

```
environment(printMe)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

So when you call:

```
with(E, printMe())
```

The function `printMe` tries to find `x` locally. It doesn´t. Then it tries to find `x` in its environment, which is the Global Enviroment *and not* the local environment of `with`. It does not find it again, then it throws an error.

To illustrate the point, see that if you define `printMe` inside `with`, the environment of `printMe` will be the local environment of `with` and it will find `x`:

```
with(E,{
  printMe <- function() {
    print(x)
  } 
  print(environment(printMe))
  printMe()
  })
<environment: 0x29785678>
[1] 1 2 3
```

Or, you could change the environment of `printMe` inside `with`:

```
with(E, {
  environment(printMe) <- environment()
  printMe()
})
[1] 1 2 3
```

Regarding your second example, when you `attach` the environment `E`, you are making the objects of `E` (i.e, `x`) available to the *Global Environment*. So when you call `printMe` in this situation, it will look for `x` in the *Global Environment* and, since `E` is attached, it will find it. That´s why it works.

I used to have the same doubts you are having, so this question may help you further: [Environments in R, mapply and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086432/environments-in-r-mapply-and-get) .

This may also help: [Understanding lexical scoping in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766649/understanding-lexical-scoping-in-r)

Comment: Thanks, this clears it up. My confusion comes from the documentation in `?with` - "Evaluate an R expression in an environment constructed from data"... This seems to be a bit misleading, at least the way I had interpreted it.

Answer (score 7):

Basically, when you use `with`, you're doing the same as

```
printMe = function() { print(x); }
local({
    x=1:3
    printMe()
})
# Error in print(x) : object 'x' not found
```

which also does not work. This has to do with how free variables are resolved in a function. When you call `printMe`, it will look to resolve variables in the enclosure itself, then it looks in the parent frame where the function was defined (it does not look where the function was called). Here, `printMe` is defined in the global environment. However, `x` is not defined in the global environment. If you do

```
printMe = function() { print(x); }
x=1:3
printMe()
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Then both `x` and `printMe` are defined in the global environment so it works. You could also change the environment of the `printMe` function

```
 environment(printMe) <- E
 printMe()
 # [1] 1 2 3
```

or define the function in the same environment as the with

```
with(E,{printMe <- function() {print(x)}; printMe()})
# [1] 1 2 3
```

The main point is, it doesn't matter what environment you call functions from, it matters what environments they were defined in.

You might want to check out the [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html) material on functional programming which goes over these properties.

Comment: Perhaps another thing to contrast this with that might help is `with(E,{printMe <- function() {print(x)}; printMe()})` which does work.

Comment: Thanks @joran. I added that example as well.

Comment: +1 Great answer, thanks for the explanation. I wish I could pick both! My confusion arises from the documentation in `?with`